# How to change content of one website using another in realtime?

Tags: java, php, processing

I need to make a web application in which there are two sites, A and B. A is like a control board with a lot of options, which will be open on a mobile device via a local server over wifi. Triggering the buttons on A should change the content on the Site B which is open on a computer in realtime. Much like a presentation but the two sites need to be different. What would be the best way to achieve this? I am a self taught programmer, with a basic knowledge of web technologies (HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, MySql) , processing and Java.

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be like running ajax requests in certain interval on site B, that checks if there's any update from site A. And any action on site A is stored in a database or file. Then upon the triggered ajax request the script on site B makes a cURL request to get the stored update from site A and changes the content on site B accordingly.

Comment: I thought the same, but i am worried that on a wifi connection there might be a lot of irregular delay, and i need a little precision. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: Please note that, if there might be a lot of irregular delay due to internet connection, the communication must be disturbed. If communication is disturbed it's impossible to fill that gap up with algorithm :)